# Creating graphics context for background calculations in Java

Tags: java, graphics, draw, java-2d

I have a bunch of Line2D that I need to perform some calculations on in a single graphics context. For example, I just need to see which ones intersect, which ones overlap, etc. The graphics never need to be displayed, just run in the background. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they never need to be displayed then you don't need to create a graphics context. Just costruct Line2D.Double (or Line2D.Float) objects with the desired coordinates and then call the [intersectsLine(Line2D)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#intersectsLine%28java.awt.geom.Line2D%29) method as needed.

For instance:

```
Line2D.Double firstLine = new Line2D.Double(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
Line2D.Double secondLine = new Line2D.Double(0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
boolean intersectionOccurs = firstLine.intersectsLine(secondLine);
```

Which should give true for intersectionOccurs if my mental graph generator is working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the graphics is somehow directly related to something that is displayed in the same program, this is probably not a good approach.  The details of which bits are touched by which drawing operation are arcane, undocumented, and in most cases not guaranteed to be consistent
from one environment to another.

For example, two lines which mathematically intersect might pass through each other 
without sharing any pixels.  Drawing triangles can produce several discreet blobs rather
than one contiguous blob.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I'm only using simple 2D geometry here so I don't see how two Line2D could possibly not share pixels if they intersect or overlap.

Comment: Single pixel wide lines form a staircase pattern.  It's easy to construct intersecting lines whose staircases do not share any pixels.  On the other side of this, if lines "fat" rather than single pixel, then lines which do not mathematically intersect can share some pixels.